# Google analytics events showing in real-time view, but not archived

Tags: java, google-app-engine, events, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics in Appengine.
I'm tracking events server side with this code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("v", "1");             // Version.
    map.put("tid", gaTrackingId);
    map.put("cid", "555");
    map.put("t", "event");         // Event hit type.
    map.put("ec", encode(category, true));
    map.put("ea", encode(action, true));
    map.put("el", encode(label, false));
    map.put("ev", encode(value, false));

    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new URL("http", "www.google-analytics.com", "/collect"), HTTPMethod.POST);
    request.addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER);
    request.setPayload(getPostData(map));

    HTTPResponse httpResponse = urlFetchService.fetch(request);
    // Return True if the call was successful.
    return httpResponse.getResponseCode();
```

But events are visible only on realtime and not in the stored section on google analytics site.
REALTIME:
[image]

Other Events section:
[image]

Comment: How long did you wait it can take up to 48 hours for data to show up in the standard reports

Comment: More than 48 hours

Comment: @Giovesoft did you solve this problem? 
I'm encountering the same problem. Have been sending events for 72+ hours and still not showing in reports

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old, but I had the exact same issue. For me, the fix was to begin supplying the "optional" event value (ev) parameter with a generic value of 1. As soon as I started doing that, all of my events were visible immediately in the non-real-time views. It also appears that I needed to send the also "optional" cid parameter even though I was already sending in the uid parameter and the documentation says that even though they're both "optional"; however one is required. It seems that the cid parameter may be given special treatment by Google. I hope it helps!